# Unexpected object assignment

Tags: python, variable-assignment, dictionary

```
class TrafficData(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.__data = {}
    def __getitem__(self, epoch):
        if not isinstance(epoch, int):
            raise TypeError()
        return self.__data.setdefault(epoch, ProcessTraffic())
    def __iadd__(self, other):
        for epoch, traffic in other.iteritems():

            # these work
            #existing = self[epoch]
            #existing += traffic

            # this does not
            self[epoch] += traffic # here the exception is thrown

        return self
```

In the above trimmed down code, I do not expect an item assignment, yet apparently one is occurring on the marked line, and throwing the following exception:

```
  File "nethogs2.py", line 130, in __iadd__
    self[epoch] += traffic
TypeError: 'TrafficData' object does not support item assignment
```

However if I instead use the preceding 2 commented out lines, no exception is thrown.

As I see it, the 2 should behave in the same way. `self[epoch]` returns a reference to an object, and it's modified in place through that objects `__iadd__`. What am I misunderstanding here? I frequently run into this problem when using dictionaries.

### Update0

It's probably worth pointing out that the values in `self.__data` have `__iadd__` defined, but not `__add__`, and I'd much prefer to modify the value in place if possible. I would also like to avoid creating a `__setitem__` method.

### Update1

Below is a test case demonstrating the problem, I've left the code above for existing answers.

```
class Value(object):
    def __init__(self, initial=0):
        self.a = initial
    def __iadd__(self, other):
        self.a += other
        return self
    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.a)

class Blah(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.__data = {}
    def __getitem__(self, key):
        return self.__data.setdefault(key, Value())

a = Blah()
b = a[1]
b += 1
print a[1]
a[1] += 2
print a[1]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> It's probably worth pointing out that
>   the values in `self.__data` have
>   `__iadd__` defined, but not `__add__`, and I'd much prefer to modify the value in
>   place if possible.

To add some precision to previous answers, under the circumstances you describe, `self[epoch] += traffic` translates exactly to:

```
self[epoch] = self[epoch].__iadd__(traffic)
```

So if all you want are the side effects of `__iadd__`, without the item-assignment part, your choices are limited to the workaround that you've already identified in the comments in the code you've posted, or calling `__iadd__` yourself -- possibly through the [`operator`](http://docs.python.org/library/operator.html?highlight=operator#operator.__iadd__) module, though I believe `operator.__iadd__(self[epoch], traffic)` has no added value compared to the simpler `self[epoch].__iadd__(traffic)` (when `self[epoch]` **does** have a `__iadd__` method).

Comment: Do you happen to know why `self[epoch] += traffic` isn't translated into `self[epoch].__iadd__(traffic)`? Other than using the "commented code" I provide, the best way I can find to keep my syntax is to provide a `__setitem__` that performs `assert self[key] is value`... or nothing at all (since the extracted reference as you show above will be modified in place)

Comment: @Matt, the _definition_ of `+=` is to perform an assignment on the left-hand operand (of either `__add__`'s or `__iadd__`'s results) -- it's just more regular that way than if it might either have the assignment or not (it matters a lot, e.g., in a `shelve` instance!). Yes, if you _do_ want to write a `__setitem__`, it can be a noop or just a check (but you did mention you'd rather _not_ write it;-).

Answer (score 6):

What you are exactly doing in:

```
self[epoch] += traffic
```

is:

```
self[epoch] = self[epoch] + traffic
```

But you haven't defined `__setitem__` method, so you can do that on self.

You also need:

```
def __setitem__(self, epoch, value):
        self.__data[epoch] = value
```

or something similar.

Comment: can you link to some documentation on this syntactical fact?

Comment: Here operators are described. Don't know exactly where to find it in official docs: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_basic_operators.htm

Comment: @SilentGhost, no I meant the `a += b -> a = a + b` thing.

Comment: This: http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#emulating-numeric-types.  "If x is an instance of a class that does not define a __iadd__() method..."

Comment: @Matt:  See also Augmented Assignment Statements, http://docs.python.org/reference/simple_stmts.html#augmented-assignment-statements

Comment: @S.Lott, but it _does_ define `__iadd__`

Comment: @Will, the link appears to be on the right topic, but doesn't explain why my in-place add (`__iadd__`) method is not being invoked...

Comment: @Matt: `self[epoch]` is what type?  Does that type define `__iadd__`?

Comment: @S.Lott: yes it does. I've distilled out the situation in Update1 in my question.

Answer (score 0):

The code:

```
self[epoch] += traffic
```

Is syntactic sugar for:

```
self[epoch] = self[epoch] + traffic
```

So **the assignment is not unexpected it is the assignment in `+=`**. So you also need to override the `__setitem__()` method.